# Create dictionary from list of lists. Append items to dictionary value if key exist

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
 My_dict={0: ['Name1', 'value1', 'value2',  'value3'],
 1: ['Name2',  'value4', 'value5',  'value6'],
  2: ['Name1',  'value7', 'value8',  'value9']}
```

and I need to created another dictionary from it  - with first value from list as key and for those keys which are duplicated - append values to list of values.
As the result I want to see is:

```
New_dict= {'Name1': ['value1','value2','value3','value7','value8','value9'],
           'Name2': ['value4', 'value5',  'value6']}
```

Now I'm thinking about turning dictionary into list of lists and creating new dictionary(but I rewrite values when creating new dictionary)

```
lists=[]
My_dict={0: ['Name1', 'value1', 'value2',  'value3'],
 1: ['Name2',  'value4', 'value5',  'value6'],
  2: ['Name1',  'value7', 'value8',  'value9']}
for v in My_dict.items():
    lists.append(v[1])
new_dict={x[0]: x[1:] for x in lists}
```

Any ideas where should I add if statement for verifying that I'm appending values to existing key in new_dict, not rewriting

Comment: Does the order matter? Will there be duplicates within the list?

Comment: It's better to sort, but not so important. Yes, a lot of duplicates can be there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for key in sorted(My_dict):
...     d[My_dict[key][0]].extend(My_dict[key][1:])
... 
>>> 
>>> dict(d)
{'Name1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value7', 'value8', 'value9'], 'Name2': ['value4', 'value5', 'value6']}
```

In Python 3.6 and newer you can omit `sorted()` and just iterate over `My_dict.values()` if you want to process the values in the insertion order.

In case the order of the lists' elements doesn't matter or you need to eliminate duplicates, you can use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
>>> d = defaultdict(set);
>>> for value in My_dict.values():
...     d[value[0]] |= set(value[1:])
...
>>> dict(d)
{'Name1': {'value8', 'value3', 'value2', 'value1', 'value7', 'value9'}, 'Name2': {'value4', 'value5', 'value6'}}
```

Comment: And in case when order matters? Will investigate deeply on data what I'm trying to deal with but thanks in advance for answer)

Comment: oh I've found >>> # dictionary sorted by value
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))